# Three.js prevent seeing file in resources

Tags: javascript, security, stl, three.js, resources

When user click to specific 3Dmodel I get it from server render and display in browser using three.js. Some of models are free and some of them has a price. The problem comes when user click to model which is not free - and in fact he can go to console -> resources and see stl file and download it. Is there any option to avoid this? Is there option like decode something or hide from resource??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the web, so the answer is no: the data has to get to the browser to be displayed..

You can make it more difficult for people to copy your models directly from the resources-tab though. The possibilities are endless and only limited by your imagination.

Some inspiration:

- you can use your own file-format instead of collada. Especially if you are just handling static models, that could be straightforward.
- maybe use a compression-library so there'll just be a binary-blob without content-type indication in the resources-tab (look at http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ or https://github.com/nodeca/pako for instance)
- in modern browsers you can also use the web-cryptography API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) to send a properly encrypted file to the browser.

But I think as soon as you have a way to obscure the filetype using any method you like, your problem will effectively be solved. However you do this, it will always be possible to intercept the data before it's being rendered, but at that point it's probably an effort not many people will invest.